# Android 3d math library (vector, matrix, etc.) similar to javax.vecmath.Matrix4f.rotate()

Tags: java, android, math, 3d, rotation

New to Android here.

Is there an Android 2.2 3D math library in the SDK?  I couldn't find one and I was hoping there would be one. I am not able to use javax.* packages for some reason in Eclipse.

The thing I really need is rotation about an arbitrary axis of an arbitrary angle.

I don't really want to use the NDK unless I am forced to. If there is a freely available Java 3d math library, I would love to know. It should work with Android.

It should ideally have basic 3d math like cross(), dot(), etc. along with arbitrary rotation and scaling.

Thanks,

Comment: javax.* is still not supported on android (yet), sucks, i know :(

Answer (score 2):

I just dropped the vecmath source in to my project and it seems to compile and work fine apart from Color* classes (which is no great loss).

Comment: vecmath is GPL. For me it's a problem.

Comment: That's news to me, or I would certainly have mentioned it (and it will be a significant irritation to us too).

Comment: [link](http://sage.math.washington.edu/tmp/sage-2.8.12.alpha0/local/java/sun-libs/vecmath.license) I think this is the right link. Not GPL, although not totally liberal either. Strictly speaking, the simple modification I suggested would appear to be disallowed in a commercial context. Boo.

Comment: I guess the authorative source for vecmath is http://java.net/projects/vecmath. SVN history shows that they switched to GPL v2 on Feb 28, 2008. Before that date, the license was [different](http://java.net/projects/vecmath/sources/svn/content/trunk/LICENSE.txt?rev=111). I guess you still can check out the old version and use it under the old terms.

Comment: Sorry here's the [correct link to the license](http://java.net/projects/vecmath/sources/svn/content/trunk/LICENSE.txt?rev=126) and [the last commit under the old license](http://java.net/projects/vecmath/sources/svn/show?rev=126). @peter, thank you for the license pointer.

Comment: Now that I read the [actual JDL license](http://java.net/projects/vecmath/sources/svn/content/trunk/LICENSE-JDL.txt?rev=126) I come to the conclusion that it only lets you use vecmath **to implement the Java 3D specification**. Meaning that it's even more restrictive than GPL.

Comment: Hmmm, I could've sworn that vecmath.jar was basically ok to use in a fairly broad range of circumstances, and assumed it wouldn't be too problematic to use in a way similar to what I described. I only used the modified source for a very basic test app that I haven't distributed, although I use vecmath for something rather bigger (also not public just yet). When it says 'to implement the Java 3D specification' it could mean the part of it to do with vector maths, it doesn't necessarily mean to support the wider graphics API. I might read the license again later.

Comment: It says: _"2.1 ... Sun grants to You [lots of cool stuff to do with the] code and related documentation ..., but only as part of Your own Compatible Implementation (as defined below) ..."_. Then it says, _"3.1.1 A Compatible Implementation must comply with the full Specification ... 3.1.2 A Compatible Implementation must ... pass the most current compatibility requirements ..."_ In this case it's Java3D, and I read it as you can use the licensed code only if you actually develop a fully compatible Java3D implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find was the [math package](http://code.google.com/p/jmonkeyengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fengine%2Fsrc%2Fcore%2Fcom%2Fjme3%2Fmath) of [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/). It required some modification to work in separation from the rest of the engine. Specifically you only want to keep `Matrix*f`, `Vector*f`, `Quaternion`, and `FastMath` classes, and remove any methods that depend on classes from other packages. Luckily the BSD license makes this possible for any purpose.

Comment: Looks reasonable on first glance. Would probably be sensible to make a new BSD project of the separated version? I don't see much point leaving any of the classes out if they can easily be left in; looks like a useful set of basic functionality. How much dependency on other packages is there, do you know?

Comment: @peter, For the most part I had to strip the use of the `Savable` interface and associated methods because it pulled in the `export` package which in turn pulled `asset` which seemed to depend on every single class in the engine.  Then I removed any methods using `TempVars` from `util` because `TempVars` depended on `scene` and `collision` packages. Then I removed unneeded classes from `math` because each class required cleanup and I wanted to minimize my work.