# Is there a Vector3f class in Android?

Tags: android

I've been looking up 3D tutorials in OpenGL, and almost all tutorials I find uses the Vector3f class.

Googling for a Vector3f class returns a class within the `android.renderscript.*` package. But, in vanilla Android 2.3.3 SDK, I do not find any `android.renderscript.*` package.

Could anyone tell me where I can find the Vector3f class in vanilla Android 2.3.3? Thanks!

Comment: look for tutorials for openGL ES instead.

Comment: Yeah! How stupid I am for not looking this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android suports OpenGL **ES** not OpenGL. It sounds the same but it is not. Tutorial on OpenGL may be useful to get some generic fundamentals, but you should look for OpenGL ES tutorial (be it Android or iOS) as many things differ enough to make OpenGL tutorials not work on ES

I found this [worth reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179249/opengl-vs-opengl-es-2-0-can-an-opengl-application-be-easily-ported)

Answer (score 0):

there is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/package-summary.html. also see [Import javax.vecmath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381291/import-javax-vecmath)

Comment: The `vecmath` is for Java applications, not for Android. :/

Comment: please see the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112269/android-3d-math-library-vector-matrix-etc-similar-to-javax-vecmath-matrix4f